# creating navigational menus in html css javascript jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I want to make such kind of menus when I click the holiday/seasonal then all of its related list open. For example:

[image: screenshot]

I have searched the internet for submenus but it is not giving right method. If you know the right method for creating this menus, please share the link or give some guidance!

Answer (score 0):

My first suggestion would be to use two nested `<ul>`s (pointed lists), both with attribute `list-style-type: none`, as in [**this fiddle**](https://jsfiddle.net/d0698kLp/12/). This no-JS solution opens the submenu when just  hovering, not clicking.